networknt json-schema-validator -> Can i override validation for existing Keyword?
In networknt/json-schema-validator, the maximum keyword accepts only number type as argument.
In AJV json schema validator, maximum keyword accepts both number type as well as string or json pointer using $data custom keyword.
If I want to implement the same in networknt/json-schema-validator, is there a way to override the existing maximum keyword validation ?
I tried the recommended way to add a custom keyword and validation for this by adding the keyword maximum . But it didn't work.
